# Is it necessary to add col-md selector in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried searching for an answer to this to no avail.  Basically what I'm wondering is if it is necessary to specify a col-md-* value in Bootstrap 3, or if you can just use, say, col-xs-12 and col-sm-* and have the col-sm-* value dictate the col size all the way to some massive display.

This seems like a no-brainer (that having col-sm would be fine) but the documentation includes seemingly redundant col-md-* values as well, such as here (taken from "Example: Mobile, Tablet, and Desktop" under "Grid System" in CSS section:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4 .col-md-4</div>
  <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Any clarification here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Your intuition is correct, the lowest value you set (xs, sm or md) will dictate for the larger screen sizes; that means if you want your div to span 4 columns starting at small devices and all the way up, you just have to set `.col-sm-4`.

It works this way because of how the media queries are set up:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, up to 480px) */ 
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */ 
@media (min-width: @screen-tablet) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */ 
@media (min-width: @screen-desktop) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */ 
@media (min-width: @screen-large-desktop) { ... }
```

If not overridden, classes for small devices will apply to larger screens as well

Comment: Thanks! For some reason this doesn't always seem to be the case for me, but I would assume that it's down to human error on my part. The main manifestation of this that I see is col-md not expanding up to col-lg when involving offsets.

Comment: @JeffW I made a simple test case with offsets and it seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/Lde6n/show/ make sure you're using the latest version of the CSS files as I remember seeing the release candidates didn't have the offset feature well implemented. If that doesn't solve it maybe you can post a fiddle with the markup you're using to see if we can sort out the issue

Comment: Very helpful and trashing my question that I have written and waiting to post in another tab.

Comment: Expanding:  I wonder if the bootstrap engineers (cheers to these guys) if they would consider setting up a class match of "col-x" which would be the default column definition to use in such a case, to be honest, it feels a little wrong using col-xs-x as a default (although I understand why it works).

Comment: I've expanded on the original jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Lde6n/4/show/ and it looks to me like we may not understand the xs implementation correctly, that you wouldn't use xs in this manner, and primarily because offsets are not defined for xs.  The smallest grid definition you would than use is sm.  Although, I'm still a little perplexed as these column definitions also have a max-width definition, so not sure how that works. :/